# Неоднозначный вызов функции класса

Tags: c++

Почему компилятор пишет

> error: call to member function 'foo' is ambiguous

ведь я явно указал тип литерала `unsigned long long`?

```
class A {
    using LL = long long;

public:
    void foo(unsigned LL) {}

    void foo(LL) {}
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.foo(42ull);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот здесь

```
void foo(unsigned LL) {}
```

`LL` должно восприниматься как параметр функции типа `unsigned int`. А далее, поскольку у вас есть функции от `unsigned int` и `long long`, а передаете вы `unsigned long long` - точного соответствия нет, и вызов неоднозначен...

```
class A {
    using LL = long long;
    using ULL = unsigned long long;

public:
    void foo(ULL) {}

    void foo(LL) {}
};
```

и все заработает :)

`typedef` - не препроцессор, присоединение `unsigned` к определенному таким образом типу не работает.

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле первый вариант перегруженной функции-члена `foo` имеет параметр типа `unsigned int`, а не `unsigned long long int`, как вы, наверное, хотели задать. В данном случае `LL` — имя параметра, а не *typedef-name*.

[[dcl.spec]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.spec#general-3):

> If a *type-name* is encountered while parsing a *decl-specifier-seq*, it
> is interpreted as part of the *decl-specifier-seq* if and only if **there**
> **is no previous *defining-type-specifier* other than a *cv-qualifier*** in
> *the decl-specifier-seq*. ...

Таким образом, компилятор при *overload resolution* встречает 2 кандидата: `void foo(unsigned int)` и `void foo(long long int)`, оба из которых требуют *integral conversion*, поэтому имеют одинаковый ранг, и компилятор выдаёт описанное вами сообщение.